# Failed to start program. Path or permissions wrong? in Qt Creator

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I am compiling http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager. The `Win32SysInfo` project is getting built and debugged, but `DiskImager` project is giving me errors while debugging.

The error is:
`Starting ...\Win32DiskImager.exe...
Failed to start program. Path or permissions wrong?
...\Win32DiskImager.exe exited with code -1`

Comment: That solution is not working for me. Before posting this question, I have tried solution of that similar question.

Comment: I created another project and copied all the required files in the new project. Now, I am able to debug the project. I can't post this and mark it as answer.